# Netsuite transaction summary box for custom transactions

Tags: javascript, oracle, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

i'm trying to figure out how to create a transaction summary box 
[transaction sumary box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTRiO.png)  for a custom transaction.
For example transaccion summary box are natively for sales order or any standard transaction in netsuite.

Is it possible to make this in a "standard way" without suitescript?

i have read on a forum that this feature of a summary box is not supported for custom transaction. can someone confirm this?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the 2020.1 release, a new kind of custom transaction type is available called "Sales".  This custom transaction type has the Summary box built-in to it.